# An object as a parameter/argument in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, object, parameters, arguments

I've been messing around in Ruby, thinking of making simple little RPG games. It's been going decently (already have character creation mostly done). But, I was having trouble finding out how to make an attack method (or other kinds of targeted methods, like healing). For example, the method would take a "user" parameter and "target" parameter. It would use the user's stats to influence the target's HP. I've looked for info on this, but I haven't been able to "get" what the threads were about. I'm a beginner, so I'm not even sure if they were speaking of what I'm trying to find out.

Here's basically what I want. Of course, this doesn't work:

```
 class Enemy
      attr_accessor :hp, :power
      def initialize (hp, power)
           @hp = hp
           @power = power
      end
 end
 class Hero
      attr_accessor :hp, :power
      def initialize (hp, power)
           @hp = hp
           @power = power
      end
 end

 monster = Enemy.new(7,3)
 dude = Hero.new(10,5)

 def attack(user,target)
      user.hp - target.power
 end

 puts "Dude's HP is #{dude.hp}, and power is #{dude.power}"
 puts "Monster's HP is #{monster.hp}, and power is #{monster.power}"

 puts " "

 puts "Dude attacks!"

 attack(dude, monster)

 puts "Dude's HP is #{dude.hp}, and power is #{dude.power}"
 puts "Monster's HP is #{monster.hp}, and power is #{monster.power}"

 puts " "

 puts "Monster attacks!"

 attack(monster, dude)

 puts "Dude's HP is #{dude.hp}, and power is #{dude.power}"
 puts "Monster's HP is #{monster.hp}, and power is #{monster.power}"

 x = gets
```

I apologize if this is an extremely noobie question, but I'm just not finding it. If another post has the answer (in a way I can understand), please point me to it.

Perhaps I should also give my code for character creation and stats, so you know what I'm working with?

Thank you for reading my question, and hopefully answering.

Comment: As much as I understood from your question that you are looking for idea for implementing your **attack** method. If I am right then your are at wrong place bro. Please specify what you were trying, what is wrong append and how you were trying other than no one can help any one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
def attack(user,target)
  user.hp -= target.power
end
```

But I really think you should write it with OOP style like:

```
class Common
  attr_accessor :hp, :power

  def initialize(hp, power)
    self.hp = hp
    self.power = power
  end

  def hit(target)
    p "#{self.class} hits #{target.class}"
    target.hp = [target.hp - power, 0].max # you don't want hp less then 0 possible
  end
end

class Hero < Commom; end
class Enemy < Common; end
```

Then use it like

```
monster = Enemy.new(7,3)
dude = Hero.new(10,5)

moster.hit(dude)
dude.hit(monster)
```

Comment: ... And I had my math wrong, and if I hadn't, I would not have needed this thread. Thank you! I believe I'll still go with the first method for most things, though

Comment: @Natheus no problem for helping. If I understand you right my answer is correct so you probably should to choose it.